# OpenGL Mouse Input - Draw Function

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, mouse, glfw

I wish to draw lines from mouse button input (left button). I've configured a callback and it works so I can get the position back and store it for further drawings, but for some reason I am not being able to draw them.

THE CODE BELOW IS FOR TRIANGLES, I THOUGHT IT WOULD BE EASIER TO SEE, BUT I'M STILL STUCK

```cpp
double data[6];
int i = 0;
int* ptr = &i;

void mouse_input_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
  if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS && *ptr < 6)
  {
    glfwGetCursorPos(window, &data[i], &data[i + 1]);
    *ptr += 2;
  }
}
```

```cpp
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_input_callback);


  if (*ptr == 6)
  {

    for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
      fdata[r] = (float)(0.001)*data[r];
      std::cout << fdata[r] << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned int vb;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vb);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(fdata), fdata, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0));
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2*sizeof(float), (void*)0); 

    shader.Use();
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Shader below:

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0)
in vec2 position;

void main()
{   
    gl_Position = vec4(position,0.0,1.0);
};
```